# Wordpress 4 very slow in fresh install

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I just installed Wordpress 4.1 in localhost, i'm not using any custom theme or plugin, but when i want to access to admin or my website, it takes too much time to open the page.

Any solution please?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, with 4Go Ram, Intel Core i5

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Wordpress is it looks online for google fonts, gravatars and updates at wordpress.org. So even on localhost it still tries to search online. If you have a slow connection your localhost comes to a crawl.

The solution is disconnect your internet connection when it's bad, and install the 'disable google fonts' plugin. That will make a huge difference. Other than that you just have to live with the various 'error' messages about problems with wordpress.org.

Comment: It doesn't check for updates, etc on each page load - they are handled using `wp-cron`.  Google Fonts should be cached after the first page load, so they also won't cause significant problems.

Comment: Nope. This gives me endless headaches. The plugin to disable the google fonts helped a lot. The main issue is when in wp-admin.

Comment: How are you loading Google Fonts so that they load while in wp-admin?  They should only be loading on the front end.

Comment: It's the gravatar and the wordpress.org that cause the main problems in wp-admin. If (like it mostly is) my connection is bad it takes forever to move around the admin menus. The site itself depends on the theme used. Nowadays I just use the twentyfifteen theme and customise it, as it seems to cause the least problems. It's a pain trying to develop a site when you have to wait so long between page loads.

Comment: Here's the common error message, from the localhost site itself, ie not in admin, but the admin message is the same. `WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in C:\websites\lccs\wp-includes\update.php on line 295`

Answer (score 0):

Just add define in wp-config.php file: *define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true)*
This will block all internet connection.